# Getting Android arrow group indicator

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-spinner

I just noticed that some android apps have a list view with a text and a arrow like the one from the expandable list view arrow indicator. I tried to search the api demos and the web to learn how can I fetch this icon.

The idea is then use this arrow to a list view and make the list view row act like a spinner.

The following image from ADW Launcher settings can give an idea of what I want

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found out that you achieve that functionality using Android Preferences for more info follow this [tutorial](http://android-journey.blogspot.pt/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html)

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should explain how to achieve _"fetch the icon, use the icon and make the row act like a spinner"_.